# Vue.js ¿Cómo es una plantilla de un componente completo?

Tags: vue.js

Cual es el *"esqueleto"* completo de un componente de vue (component.vue)?
Se que tiene template, script y style, pero en la parte de script me gustaría saber todo lo que podría tener, me refiero a cosas como name, props, created , mounted, data, etc...

Comment: y leiste la documentacion? porque esta todo ahi...

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Respuesta actualizada

Estaba buscando unas cosas en la documentación y pude observar que si están todos los elementos de un componente de vue en la documentación oficial de Vue.js. El problema es que no están identificados como parte del "esqueleto" de un componente. Están separados en diferentes grupos según temática y mezclado con otro tipo de elementos (p.e. el, v-bind, key, slot...). Desde luego esa presentación no es asequible para los que están empezando con el framework. Por tanto, actualizo con los que he podido identificar como parte del "esqueleto" completo de un componente.

- [s] String
- [o] {}
- [f] function
- [a] Array

**Opciones / Datos**

- data [f]
- props [a, o] (Según el formato que elijas)
- propsData [o]
- computed [o]
- methods [o]
- watch [o]

**Opciones / Hooks de Ciclo de Vida**

- beforeCreate [f]
- created [f]
- beforeMount [f]
- mounted [f]
- beforeUpdate [f]
- updated [f]
- activated [f]
- deactivated [f]
- beforeDestroy [f]
- destroyed [f]
- errorCaptured [f]

**Opciones / Composición**

- mixins [a]

**Opciones / Recursos**

- components [a, o] (Según el formato que elijas)

No las he tenido que usar todas, solo las que facilité en mi respuesta anterior. Del igual modo, te invito a consultar la documentación si quieres saber que hace cada una.

---

### Respuesta anterior

> Entiendo tu pregunta, en la documentación no lo aclaran del todo,
> tienes que buscar cosas muy concretas y no te listan todo lo que puede
> tener. Te puedo decir los que yo he encontrado, marco los tipos del
> siguiente modo:
>
> - [s] String
> - [o] {}
> - [f] function
> - [a] Array
>
> los que yo conozco son los siguientes:
>
> - name [s]
> - props [a, o] (Según el formato que elijas)
> - mixins [a]
> - components [a, o] (Según el formato que elijas)
> - data [f]
> - created [f]
> - mounted [f]
> - destroyed [f]
> - beforeDestroy [f]
> - watch [o]
> - computed [o]
> - methods [o]
>
> Creo que he puesto todas las que conozco por que las he usado todas.
> Desconozco si hay más porque como ya sabrás la documentación no las
> lista. Si quieres saber que hace cada una te sugiero ir a la
> documentación que eso si lo vas a encontrar.

Comment: Es un tanto contradictorio que digas primero: *porque como ya sabrás la documentación no las lista* pero después indicas *te sugiero ir a la documentación que eso si lo vas a encontrar.* ya que primero dices que no están y luego que si

Comment: Y lo reafirmo, la documentación no las lista. No hay un listado completo. Pero si puedes buscar en la documentación información sobre esos temas concretos. No es lo mismo un listado que buscarlas sueltas. De hecho es lo primero que le digo en mi respuesta: _en la documentación no lo aclaran del todo, tienes que buscar cosas muy concretas y no te listan todo lo que puede tener_